# How to test the representatives of a sample?

Tags: sampling

I have a data set with over 10000 measurements, then I random sample 35 measurements from this big data set. How to test that this is a representative sample. I know the central limit theory, if sample size is big enough (over 30) mean and variance are preserved. However, what test or approach I should use to show such representative. The data is continuous, and the original big data does not follow normal distribution.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you mention centra limit theory preserving the mean and variance?

Comment: Sorry, I should use other more accurate words. That is not how central limit theory say.

Comment: Then what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just as well to put the CLT and $n = 30$ aside and take a look at a few simulated examples. Then maybe you can decide what you mean by a 'representative' sample.

Suppose you have 10,000 measurements distributed as $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape = 5, rate=1/10).$ Then, theoretically, $\mu = 50, \sigma^2 = 500,$ and $\sigma \approx 22.36.$
In R, such the measurements might be simulated as follows:

```
set.seed(2020);  x = rgamma(10000, 5, .1)
```

Now let's take samples of sizes $n = 30, 100, 500$ and $5000,$ and see how close their sample means and standard deviations are to those of the population.

```
x.30 = sample(x, 30);  mean(x.30);  sd(x.30)
[1] 57.27902  # compare with 50
[1] 20.66619  # compare with 22.36
x.100 = sample(x, 100);  mean(x.100);  sd(x.100)
[1] 49.37123
[1] 20.64054
x.500 = sample(x, 500);  mean(x.500);  sd(x.500)
[1] 48.39851
[1] 21.63935
x.5000 = sample(x, 5000);  mean(x.5000);  sd(x.5000)
[1] 50.09916
[1] 22.24913
```

Roughly speaking, according to the Law of Large numbers, larger samples tend to have
sample means and standard deviations nearer to $\mu$ and $\sigma,$
respectively, than do smaller samples.

You need to decide how close these matches need to be in order for
you to call them 'representative'. That may give you an idea how 
large your samples need to be.

Here is a histogram of the 10,000 measurements simulated above, along with the density function of $\mathsf{Gamma}(5, .1).$

```
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve(dgamma(x, 5, .1), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Here is a histogram of the sample of size $n = 500$ along with a kernel density estimator (you can think of it as a 'smoothed histogram') that seeks to
approximate the gamma distribution of the measurements.

```
hist(x.500, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
lines(density(x.500), lwd=2, col="orange")
```

[image]

Are the sample mean and standard deviation the *only* features of
the sample that you care about? Or are there other considerations
in deciding what 'representative' means?